# Android Slider - can we retrieve attributes from the Item XML?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I am currently using Xamarin to create an Android app, so you're about to see C# and not Java, but if you know how to solve the same issue in Java, I would still appreciate your answer...

I have a Slider and I've set up a string array like below:

```
<string-array name="house_style_array">
  <item id="124">Item 1</item>
  <item id="565">Item 2</item>
  <item id="356">Item 3</item>
  <item id="537">Item 4</item>
</string-array>
```

I have created a ItemSelected Event and I am able to get the selected string, e.g. "Item 1" but I cannot find a way of getting the id - the following code returns an id based on the position in the string array (zero based) which is no use:

```
private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;                        
        string toast = string.Format("The selection is {0}\r\nThe ID is {1}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position), spinner.GetItemIdAtPosition(e.Position));
        Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do. I have seen examples of creating objects but it seems overly complicated for a simple ID/String scenario. I don't have any objections to altering the XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to populate the spinner using objects as below as it gives me far more flexibility:

```
Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.mySpinner);
        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                                                Resource.Layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                                new Taxonomy[] { new Taxonomy( 123, "option1"), 
                                                                 new Taxonomy( 124, "option2"), 
                                                                 new Taxonomy( 125, "option3"), 
                                                                 new Taxonomy( 126, "option4") });
        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

This allows me to add any number of properties to the object and have them easily available when the user selects an option:

```
private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        Taxonomy selectedObject = (Taxonomy)spinner.Adapter.GetItem(e.Position);

        //rest of code using selected object.
    }
```

The last this to do is override the ToString() function in the Taxonomy object to display the required data in the spinner, e.g:

```
 public override string ToString()
    {
        return TaxonomyName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string fileName = "yourfilePath";
string nodeList = "//string-array/item";
string itemInnerText = "Item 1";
string attributeName = "Id";


XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(nodeList);
foreach(XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
{
     if (node.Item(0).InnerText == itemInnerText)
         return node.Attributes[attributeName].Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer - The above probably would work but not the solution I went for - I ended up changing to use objects as the answer below - gave me far more flexibility